# Alternative Function Definitions for the Square Wave signal

Tags: special-functions, signal-processing

Are there any other function definitions for the Square Wave signal rather than the :

[image]

and those referred to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_wave)  ?

Comment: The sign-of-sine is the one I tend to use most often. Writing as a linear combination of Heaviside functions is also useful. Why would you want anything else?

Comment: I was just curious if there is a function definition of the Square Wave not including sums of other functions and consisting of only one definition, that is not having multiple definitions for different domains of the function.